# Error in if ((dimension < 1) | (dimension > n)) stop("wrong embedding dimension") : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, error-handling

my code is like the following:

```
unemp <- c(1:10)
bsp_li <- list(c(1:10),c(11:20),c(21:30))
var_data_rep <- lapply(bsp_li, function(x) {cbind(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(unemp))} ) # Create VAR data matrices
var_data_rep2 <- lapply(var_data_rep, function(x) {colnames(x) = c("rGDP", "U"); return(x)}) # Name columns
var_data_rep_ts <- lapply(var_data_rep2, function(x) {ts(x, frequency=1, start=c(1977))} ) # Make it ts again
var_data_rep_lag <- lapply(var_data_rep_ts, function(x) {VARselect(x, lag.max = 5, type = "const")} ) # Take lag with lowest SC criteria (VAR.pdf)
VARgdp_rep <- lapply(var_data_rep_ts, function(x) {VAR(x, p = var_data_rep_lag$x$selection[['SC(n)']], type = "const"); return(x)} ) # Lag=lowest SC criteria from var_data_rep_lag
```

if i run only the last line r always gives me the error:

`Error in if ((dimension < 1) | (dimension > n)) stop("wrong embedding dimension") : 
  argument is of length zero
Called from: embed(y, dimension = p + 1)`

But if im running it with `Source` then it seems to work.. any suggestions?

Comment: What packages are you using ?

Comment: i think for this bit of code only the package vars is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work (at least no error is thrown) :

```
VARgdp_rep <- 
    lapply(index(var_data_rep_ts), 
        function(x) {
                  res <- VAR(var_data_rep_ts[[x]], p = 
var_data_rep_lag[[x]]$selection[['SC(n)']], type = "const"); 
                  return(res)
          } 
       )
```

In you code, return(x) is strange because after doing VAR calculations .. you just return the x withc was pass to the function.
And $x seems to have no meaning here.

Comment: thanks! it works for me also perfectly fine! could you explain your code a bit? why are you using index? i tried your code without `res <-`and `return(res)`and it worked, thus it has to be `index()`what was missing in my code (and of course the wrongly used list syntax.. do you know a good summary about list syntax and how to access elements within list? couldnt find a good one until now)